Combine multiple embeddings to create a user representation
I’m building a recommendation system where each user interacts with sessions (topics with a title and description). I want to represent each user using their last 5 session interactions by creating a user embedding.
My idea is to use a pretrained model to generate embeddings for the session titles and descriptions, then combine the embeddings of the last 5 sessions to create a user representation.
I’d like advice on:

How to combine multiple session embeddings effectively.
Which pretrained models are best suited for this kind of text encoding.

I'm using titan-embedding-v2 and open for any other embedding models as well
Looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you!

Here are some pretrained models for text embedding:

Titan Embedding v2: If you're already using it, it's optimized for
embeddings and should suffice if its output aligns with your task.
OpenAI's Ada-002: Highly versatile and cost-efficient for
embedding tasks.
Sentence Transformers (e.g., all-MiniLM-L6-v2): Provides robust
sentence-level embeddings, optimized for semantic similarity.

